# Composer require fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: array_merge() does not accept unknown named parameters

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan, laravel-9

I'm trying to add authentification to my laravel app. As make:auth has been deprecated, I have tried both ui:auth and breeze.
Is it possible that I have to upgrade my composer? It came with version 1.10.1. when I installed it using the command line installation, even though the latest version is 2.5.1.

However, both
`composer require laravel/breeze:1.9.2`
`composer require laravel/ui`

produce the following error:

```
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^4.1 for laravel/ui
./composer.json has been updated

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: array_merge() does not accept unknown named parameters in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/DefaultPolicy.php:84
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: array_merge()
#1 /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/DefaultPolicy.php(84): call_user_func_array()
#2 /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php(387): Composer\DependencyResolver\DefaultPolicy->selectPreferredPackages()
#3 /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php(740): Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->selectAndInstall()
#4 /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php(231): Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->runSat()
#5 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(489): Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->solve()
#6 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(232): Composer\Installer->doInstall()
#7 /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php(248): Composer\Installer->run()
#8 /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php(205): Composer\Command\RequireCommand->doUpdate()
#9 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(255): Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute()
#10 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(934): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#11 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#12 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(281): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#13 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(149): Composer\Console\Application->doRun()
#14 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(113): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#15 /usr/bin/composer(62): Composer\Console\Application->run()
#16 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/DefaultPolicy.php on line 84

Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: array_merge() does not accept unknown named parameters in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/DefaultPolicy.php:84
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: array_merge()
#1 /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/DefaultPolicy.php(84): call_user_func_array()
#2 /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php(387): Composer\DependencyResolver\DefaultPolicy->selectPreferredPackages()
#3 /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php(740): Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->selectAndInstall()
#4 /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php(231): Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->runSat()
#5 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(489): Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->solve()
#6 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(232): Composer\Installer->doInstall()
#7 /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php(248): Composer\Installer->run()
#8 /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php(205): Composer\Command\RequireCommand->doUpdate()
#9 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(255): Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute()
#10 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(934): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#11 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#12 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(281): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#13 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(149): Composer\Console\Application->doRun()
#14 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(113): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#15 /usr/bin/composer(62): Composer\Console\Application->run()
#16 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/DefaultPolicy.php on line 84
```

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/breeze": "1.9.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "laravel/ui": "^4.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\": "app/",
            "Database\Factories\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\Seeders\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Update your composer version first. Then double-check your PHP version. Are you using everything locally? Xampp? Mampp?

Comment: "Is it possible that I have to upgrade my composer?" - yes, maybe. Which version of Composer do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an issue with composer and php 8.0, as stated in this issue ticket [#9097](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9097) and fixed in the newer version pull [#9076](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/9076)

Basically, update your composer.

Try updating composer with `composer self-update` if you still have the same error you will need to manually update it.

If you are not familiar with the manual method, ask someone that knows to help you.

1. `sudo apt install wget php-cli php-zip unzip`
2. `php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`
3. `HASH="$(wget -q -O - https://composer.github.io/installer.sig)"`
4. `php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '$HASH') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"`

> ```
> Installer verified
> ```

5. `sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`

> ```
> All settings correct for using Composer
> Downloading...
> Composer (version 2.0.14) successfully installed to: 
> /usr/local/bin/composer
> Use it: php /usr/local/bin/composer
> ```

Comment: I am getting Installer Currupt. What to do now??

Comment: @Dharmik "If you are not familiar with the manual method, ask someone that knows to help you". The error you are getting means that what you downloaded (step 2) is not the one signed with the hash (step 3). you can refer to https://www.cloudsigma.com/installing-and-using-composer-on-ubuntu-18-04/